# Wordpress fails when my post is larger than 1400 words

Tags: errors, hosting

I have a self-hosted wordpress blog with bluehost. I pretty much have all settings set to default. I've had it for a couple of weeks, and just today, when I try to edit a published post I get a redirect back to the main posts page and the changes are not saved. I went back and saved increasing chunks of the content to see if there was a weird character or something, and I found out that around 1400 words it pretty consistently fails.

I have tried changing the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` in my `wp-config.php` but I don't see any erros in `wp-content/debug.php`.

I have also deactivated all my plugins and the theme. Same error.

I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: do you have the access to the /error.log file? Are you using nginx. I think this is on BH. Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: @prosti You brought me one step closer! I found this line in `wp-admin/error_log` `POST data can't be buffered; all data discarded in Unknown on line 0` Still no idea of how to fix it

Comment: Sounds like a PHP config error, like your reaching a max_input_vars limit, or something.

Comment: I spent an hour with bluehost tech support and they said they "re-built the wp-core files". Not sure what that means, but that fixed it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @nachocab If you got it fix by tech support then post this as an answer by providing as much detail as you have regarding your solution. Even if minor detail/hint you got from tech support then you should share it as an answer Because not all users use to read comments.